# How to get particular element from list of tuples

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

I have this list of tuples:

```
l1 = [(1, 8), (6, 8), (8, 7), (2, 6)]
```

I want to compare 1st element of each tuple with 1st element of next tuple
How can I access the next tuple's 1st element?

Since operating lists is a bit easier than tuples, I first made this as list of list as follows:

```
l1 = [[1, 8], [6, 8], [8, 7], [2, 6]]
```

and then tried this:

```
for i in l1:
    if l1[i][1] == l1[i+1][1]:
...
```

but l1[i+1][1] doesn't work
what am I doing wrong in (i+1) code

Comment: You *can* use tuple in this case, and it shouldn't create any hindrance. Because of `i+1` you might encounter `IndexError`. So, update your loop to range till `len(l1)-1` and use an iterator for accessing value from a list/tuple.

Comment: You are actually iterating over the elements of a list, and not the indexes: when you do `for i in l1` you are getting the first element of the list, rather than the index of the element. As suggested in the first answer, to get the index you should use `range`

Answer (score 2):

Try to use range with the length of your list -1 :

```py
for i in range(len(l1) - 1) :
    if l1[i][0] == l1[i+1][0]:
         ...
```

with this you won't get indexError when reaching your last member of the list.

Answer (score 0):

While comparing adjacent elements when traversing through the elements always make sure your stopping condition is the second last element.

Also if you are comparing the first element your indexing should start at 0 and not 1.

```
for i in range(len(l1)-1):
    if l1[i][0] == l1[i+1][0]:
```